# How to add custom drawer in drawerNavigator, react navigation 4.x?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having problem with custom drawer navigator. all the methods on internet address lower versions of react navigation which do not work anymore.
here's my code

```
import { createAppContainer,DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
import {SafeAreaView,ScrollView,Dimensions,View} from 'react-native';

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({ 
  Home: HomeScreen, 
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
},{
  contentComponent:CustomDrawerComponent,
}) 

const CustomDrawerComponent = (props) => {
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View>
      <Image source={{'uri' : 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg'}} />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />

    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
}

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

the code works fine without custom drawer. but when i add custom drawer the links on the sidebar do not appear. the side bar is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this

```
const CustomDrawerComponent = (props) => {
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View>
      <Image source={{'uri' : 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg'}} />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />

    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
}
```

i created a new react component

```
class CustomDrawerComponent React.Componect{
 render(){
return(
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View>
      <Image source={{'uri' : 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg'}} />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />

    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
}
}
```

this worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your import to import from `react-navigation-drawer`.

If you're using `react-navigation-drawer` 1.x:

```js
import { DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```

If you're using `react-navigation-drawer` 2.x, use `DrawerNavigatorItems` instead:

```js
import { DrawerNavigatorItems as DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```

Always read the official docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#providing-a-custom-contentcomponent